# IF NOT EXISTS INSERT, ELSE UPDATE -- not working for?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

here i want to update item_quatity if exist else insert row

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------------+
| id |user_id | item_id   | item_quantity |
+----+--------+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | 16     | 4         | 1             |
|  2 | 5      | 6         | 2             |
+----+--------+-----------+---------------+

INSERT INTO user_items 
SET user_id = 16 ,item_id = 4 , item_quantity = 1 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE item_quantity = item_quantity + '1' ;

OR

    INSERT INTO user_items 
         (user_id,item_id,item_quantity) VALUES ('16','4','1') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE item_quantity= item_quantity + '1' ;
```

This query always insert row , update is not working ???

Comment: Your table schema please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exist what? user_id? item_id? or both `user_id, item_id`?

add a UNIQUE constraint on column `user_id,item_id` and it will work,

```
ALTER TABLE user_items ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (user_id, item_id)
```

that is if you want to have unique compound column `user_id, item_id`

Comment: alter user_item gives error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user_items ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq (user_id, item_id)' at line 1 <br>
yes , i want compound column user_id , item_id

Comment: sorry for the typo, it should be `ALTER TABLE user_items ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (user_id, item_id)`

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into user_items (id, user_id ,item_id , item_quantity) values(3,16, 4, 1) 
on duplicate key update item_quantity = item_quantity + 1
```